# Bend a vector image (text) with script language

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, svg, vector-graphics

We want to show a dynamic text (ttf font, or similar) in a generated vector image (svg, pdf) and it should be bended similar like the names on a football shirt. Is there any command line tool or other possibility to do that? It is important that it is a vector graphic since the output will be printed on cloths!

Thanks a million.

Comment: PNG isn't a vector image format.

Comment: What's your programming-related questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SVG and its [textPath Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextOnAPath). This Element allows to place text along a path, which is exactly what you need. You don't need a script language or special tools. You just have to generate plane svg, best with a svg library, depending on the environment and language you prefer.

Comment: How is the current SVG support on droids? Can you just source it for an imageView or do you need special extensions?

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick has a rich text feature, please check out.